# How to replace the string values stored with in a variable in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, replace, null

I got an xml in output for the web-services. I have the result in the variable and I stored the result in that variable. Now I want to replace the strings in that variable. How to replace the strings in that variable.
For example:

```
//SDZZmaterialGroupList* result = (SDZZmaterialGroupList*)value;
```

in that result variable I stored the result is:

```
</Text></item>
<item>
    <Matkl>00101</Matkl>
    <Text>Steels</Text>
</item>
<item>
    <Matkl>00107</Matkl>
    <Text>Miscelleanous</Text>
</item>
<item>
    <Matkl>002</Matkl>
    <Text>Electronics</Text>
</item>
<item>
    <Matkl>00207</Matkl>
    <Text>Monitors</Text>
</item>
<item>
    <Matkl>003</Matkl>
    <Text>Bulbs</Text>
</item>
<item>
    <Matkl>007</Matkl>
    <Text>Services</Text>
</item>
<item>
    <Matkl>008</Matkl>
    <Text>Packaging</Text>
</item>
<item>
    <Matkl>01</Matkl>
    <Text>Material Group 01</Text>
</item>
<item>
    <Matkl>02004</Matkl>
    <Text>Parts</Text>
</item>
```

Now I want to replace the tags with empty value so that I can display the values (numbers) only in the iPhone?
Let me help out of this problem?

Comment: This question is difficult to understand, can you improve it? I've added code formatting so that we can at least see the xml tags you are talking about but I'm still not sure what you are trying to do. Perhaps if you supplied an example of the output you would like to arrive at we would have a better idea what you want to do. It would also help to explain what the `SDZZmaterialGroupList` class is so that we have some idea how you might access the data it contains.

Comment: 00101 Steels                                                   00107  Miscelleanous

Comment: In this way we need to get the output Plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using webservies, soap itself parse the Xml and store the value automatically.

You have to just create the object of that specific class. and access the values through that object.

See Following Example:

SDZZmaterialGroupList* result = (SDZZmaterialGroupList*)value;

result.name or result.item

check that "SDZZmaterialGroupList.h" class for its result.value

Comment: can you explain me in briefly

Comment: can u show me the SDZZmaterialGroupList.h class,so i can help you easliy

Comment: this is what the SDZZmaterialGroupList.h class looks like

Comment: /*
 SDZZmaterialGroupList.h
 The interface definition of properties and methods for the SDZZmaterialGroupList object.
 Generated by SudzC.com
*/

Comment: @interface SDZZmaterialGroupList : SoapObject
{
 NSString* _Matkl;
 NSString* _Text;
 
}

Comment: + (SDZZmaterialGroupList*) newWithNode: (CXMLNode*) node;
 - (id) initWithNode: (CXMLNode*) node;
 - (NSMutableString*) serialize;
 - (NSMutableString*) serialize: (NSString*) nodeName;
 - (NSMutableString*) serializeAttributes;
 - (NSMutableString*) serializeElements;

@end

Comment: This is not a way to post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create an [NSXMLParserDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and extract the numbers that way.